# get number of buffers in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

How does on get the current number of buffers, excluding internal buffers, in Emacs?

I have this, but it looks convoluted

```
;; number of buffers excluding internal buffers                                 
(apply '+ (mapcar
           (lambda (b)
             (if (or (buffer-file-name b)
                     (not (string-equal (substring (buffer-name b) 0 1) " ")))
                 1 0))
           (buffer-list)))
```

What it does is count the buffers that are either visiting a file or whose
name doesn't start with a space.

I just want to add the number of buffers to the frame title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of a single function that does this, but here's your
code, simplified:

```lisp
(cl-count-if
 (lambda (b)
   (or (buffer-file-name b)
       (not (string-match "^ " (buffer-name b)))))
 (buffer-list))
```